# NestJS Config partial registration with validation

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

In the NestJS documentation there is a section about [partial registration](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#partial-registration).
It says it allows to load feature-specific configuration files in different directories:

```js
import databaseConfig from './config/database.config';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forFeature(databaseConfig)],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

However, it seems that it is not possible to provide a feature-specific validation schema, as `Config` is the [only argument](https://github.com/nestjs/config/blob/bffc844de20bef87e0032dee75af4b8347784e02/lib/config.module.ts#L119) that you can give to the `forFeature` method.
Am I correct to assume that I would need to provide this database config validation schema in the `ConfigModule.forRoot` method?
This seems to defeat the purpose of a feature specific configuration file as the validation would need to be defined higher up?

Are there other ways to achieve partial registration with validation?

Answer (score 2):

There is different ways to accomplish validations using the `forFeature()` method. I admit that they are not so evident and the documentation does not mention an example.

I was in your position before and I didn't know how to do it, that's why I have created an article [here](https://dev.to/rrgt19/ways-to-validate-environment-configuration-in-a-forfeature-config-in-nestjs-2ehp) with a recap of all the possible ways that I can think of.

I will show you here a quick way in case anyone needs a fast solution and doesn't have time to read my article.

### Using Joi

Install the required dependency:

```
npm install --save joi
```

Let's create a [configuration namespace](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#configuration-namespaces) and apply validations. The `databaseConfig` that you need will look like this:

```js
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as Joi from 'joi';

export default registerAs('my-app-config-namespace', () => {
  // Our environment variables
  const values = {
    nodeEnv: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    port: parseInt(process.env.PORT),
  };

  // Joi validations
  const schema = Joi.object({
    nodeEnv: Joi.string().required().valid('development', 'production'),
    port: Joi.number().required(),
  });

  // Validates our values using the schema.
  // Passing a flag to tell Joi to not stop validation on the
  // first error, we want all the errors found.
  const { error } = schema.validate(values, { abortEarly: false });

  // If the validation is invalid, "error" is assigned a
  // ValidationError object providing more information.
  if (error) {
    throw new Error(
      `Validation failed - Is there an environment variable missing?
        ${error.message}`,
    );
  }

  // If the validation is valid, then the "error" will be
  // undefined and this will return successfully.
  return values;
});
```

I hope it's helpful.